# Word 2013 cross reference to footnotes using page numbers

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to cross reference footnotes in Word 2013 using page numbers, however Word will only show page 1 as the number.  If you click the link the hyperlink works correctly.

Does anyone know how to either update or correct the references?  I have tried the F9 refresh, setting print to update all links, etc.  This function works correctly in Office 2010.

Comment: It is the same here. It's a bug. What seems to work here (you had better double-check) is to select the footnote reference (i.e. in the body text), insert your own bookmark, then use that bookmark name in the PAGEREF field that Word created earlier (or insert a PAGEREF field to that footnote).

Comment: This should have been fixed by a (very) recent update - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2863845

Comment: Thanks bibadia.  I can confirm that this hotfix does fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the problematic page number and then click F9. That solved my problem.